# relative jumps with AVR-GCC inline assembler

Tags: assembly, avr-gcc

I've just started experimenting with inline assembler in AVR-GCC.  I'm working on a macro that multiplies two 8 bit unsigned integers and stores the result in a 16 bit unsigned integer for AVRs that don't have a hardware multiply, for greater speed than using the standard C function.  The code is:

```
#ifndef UMULTFIX_H_
#define UMULTFIX_H_

#include <inttypes.h>

#define umultfix(a,b)                   \
({                          \
uint16_t product;                   \
uint8_t multiplier = a, multiplicand = b, count = 9;\
asm volatile  (                     \
"mov %A0, %1       \n\t"                    \
"ldi %B0, 0        \n\t"                    \
"clc               \n\t"                    \
"mult: ror %B0     \n\t"                    \
"ror %A0       \n\t"                \
"dec %3        \n\t"                \
"breq end      \n\t"                \
"brcc mult     \n\t"                \
"clc           \n\t"                \
"adc  %B0, %2      \n\t"                    \
"rjmp mult     \n\t"                \
"end:          \n\t"                \
:"=&r" (product): "a" (multiplier), "a" (multiplicand), "a" (count)\
);                          \
product;                        \
})
#endif /* UMULTFIX_H_ */
```

The problem is I can only use this macro once - the complier doesn't like "mult:" and "end:" being redefined when the macro is inserted to do a multiplication on a different set of arguments.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you define the following macros:

```
#define QUOTE_(x) #x
#define QUOTE(x) QUOTE_(x)
```

Then you can then build the line-number into the assembler label:

```
...
"mult_" QUOTE(__LINE__) ": ror %B0     \n\t" 
...
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately I noticed a problem - the above code works to insert a line number into the label, but how do I jump to it? I tried something like: "brcc mult"QUOTE(__LINE__-4) "\n\t" but it doesn't work.  Perhaps I'll just have to use the program counter and direct offsets instead of using labels.

Comment: @Bitrex: `QUOTE(__LINE__)` should resolve to a string version of the line number of where the `umultfix()` macro is being instantiated from.  Therefore, each time it's used, it should be unique.  (Obviously, if you use the macro in different files, you may need to use `(__FILE__)` as well.)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, in AVR gcc inline assembler, you should

> make use of the special pattern **%=**, which is replaced by a unique number on each asm statement

as described, e.g., in the ["Cookbook"](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html#asm_macros).

Then you would write something like:

```
jmp someLabel_%=
...
someLabel_%=:
...
```

The "%=" is automatically replaced by some arbitrary number which makes your label unique.

(Note: You may be heading for trouble when using labels ending in numeric literals: `myLabel_1%=` and `myLabel_12%=`, for instance, may cause conflicts.)